# How to generate 3D maps on the fly with kinect camera using octomap or rviz?

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed octomap using the source code and run the samples, which worked fine. But since I wanted on the fly 3D generation using kinect I installed ROS, open NI and rviz. I could capture point cloud data on rviz, converted it to .bt using octomap_tutor, which I further gave as input to octovis to generate 3D maps. But this is done manually and I want continuous 3D mapping i.e. on the fly 3D map generation. I found something on the forum that suggested using rviz pluggins for octomap, which I installed but I guess I'm missing the right way configure it. I also tried rviz by installing octomap_mapping and octomap_server but was unsuccessful. So please can anyone help me with the best method for on the fly 3D mapping using kinect camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247421/how-to-generate-3d-maps-on-the-fly-with-kinect-camera-using-octomap-or-rviz?/) by [cuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28456/cuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-11-07**:
Octomap is just a way to represent 3D data, it doesn't contain anything that aligns point clouds. There are packages that do do that, but more information would be helpful such as what kind of robot you're using and what kind of environment you're mapping (e.g. indoors or outdoors).

**Comment by [cuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28456/cuda/) on 2016-11-22**:
@Airuno2L I have given the details of steps followed. Can you help me solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for replying Airuno2L.

I am trying to build ROS and octomap on ubuntu 14.04 using kinect camera. I am not using any robot as of now, instead manually trying to move the camera . These are the steps I follow:

1. I run roscore
2. I launch roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
3. I launch roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch

I have made a few changes to these files after referring the previous issues faced by people and I dont know if its correct.

This is my octomap_mapping.launch file

-->
        
       
        
        
       
         -->

This is my octomap_mapping_nodelet.launch file

-->

4. I run rosrun rviz rviz
5. I add MarkerArray topic and change the topic to occupied_cells_vis_array(I also tried changing it to occupied_cells_vis but didn't work)
6. I get a fixed frame error: no tf data found. So, I run "rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 map my_frame 100" and the error is resolved but still I don't see any maps.
7. I add PointCloud2 topic

I still can't visualize any map. Please please help!

---

Originally posted by [cuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28456/cuda/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-16**:
This answer looks like it is a copy of [Unable to view 3D map on rviz](http://answers.ros.org/question/248208). Could you please decide which one you want to keep, and delete the other?

**Comment by [cuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28456/cuda/) on 2016-11-22**:
Thank you gvdhoorn. I closed the topic Unable to view 3D map on rviz. Could you help me with the solution? I'm still looking for any kind of help.